# MySQL select after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Lets asume a table like:

> ID = INT, AutoIncrement
>
> VAR = VARCHAR, 65
>
> FOO = VARCHAR, 65

I want to insert something new, and get the Auto-Generated ID, for further use.

My current solution is:

1.`INSERT into table (VAR,FOO) VALUES ('test','anothertest')`

2.`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1`

To get the last insert, but the problem is, what happends if the website lags, and there is a time gap between the queries?

example:

1. `12:00AM 0.000s -> "INSERT into table (VAR,FOO) VALUES ('test','anothertest')`
2. `12:00AM 0.500s -> "INSERT into table (VAR,FOO) VALUES ('xyz', '!!!!!`)`
3. `12:00AM 0.800s -> "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1`

the Query in 3 would not return the ID from 1, it would return the ID from 2

My Question no is, is there an absolute secure way to get a Value from a inserted Query?

like a confirmation "test, anothertest has successfully inserted into table, ID is 20"

the ID should be available as variable in php, just for information

Comment: use transaction to be sure

Comment: how? @Undefined_variable

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention PHP there is usually a specific function to get that.  If you are using the mysqli drivers then see [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Edit: According to the docs linked above `The value of the AUTO_INCREMENT field that was updated by the previous query. Returns zero if there was no previous query on the connection or if the query did not update an AUTO_INCREMENT value.` Since it is talking about queries **on the connection** then I would interpret that as meaning that queries on *other connection* (i.e. queries from other requests) won't affect the value returned.  As long as you call it dirctly after the insert (before you do anythign else) then it should work.

Caveat: I am simply interpreting the docs here.  I haven't actually tested for other calls myself.  Wouldn't be that difficult though - simply have a script which does an insert, a sleep then fetches the ID, giving you time to do another insert during the sleep.

Comment: will the mysqli_insert_id set at the insert, or at the call?, if set at the call, we would have the same problem like doing it by hand

Answer (score 1):

In php I use mysql_insert_id();

In later MySql insert/update I use LAST_INSERT_ID()

It's absolutely the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try using, Scope_Identity(). This returns the last autogenerated id.

This link has more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: The question is tagged mysql so I doubt an MS SQL Server solution will work!